# Concatenate List PYTHON

Tags: python

Is it possible to concatenate lists in python like this: line 1 from list A with line 1 from list B making a new line without any space between it, line 2 from list A with line 2 from list B, and so on?

Example:

```
A = ["AAA", "CCC" , "EEE"]
B = ["BBB", "DDD", "FFF"]
```

So the output would be:

```
C = ["AAABBB" , "CCCDDD" , "EEEFFF"]
```

I tried this code:

```
c = A + B
```

But I get a different output:

```
C = ["AAA", "CCC" , "EEE" , "BBB", "DDD", "FFF"]
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Try using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and come back here if you get stuck. Should be pretty straightforward though, especially if you look up examples.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of A and B is the same you can use list comprehension:

```
C = [A[i] + B[i] for i in range(len(A))]
```

Comment: That's not Pythonic. Try `[a+b for a,b in zip(A,B)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
C = [i + j for i, j in zip(A, B)] 
C
```

Source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-concatenate-two-lists-element-wise/

Answer (score 0):

You try this with `zip()` it might be useful for your future code works.

```
A = ["AAA", "CCC" , "EEE"]
B = ["BBB", "DDD", "FFF"]

#List comprehension

output = [a+b for a,b in zip(A,B)]
print(output)

#Using for loop without list comprehension
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    print(a+b)
    #append :)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ["AAA", "CCC" , "EEE"]
B = ["BBB", "DDD", "FFF"]

C = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    C.append(A[i] + B[i])

print(C)
```

This too works. Hope it helped you!

Comment: Dont you think, saying `range(3)` will become invalid, when items in list is increased? Better to use `range(len(A))`, assuming both list are same size.